# Definition of Chromatic Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

How could the following two definitions of chromatic polynomials be the same?

> The chromatic polynomial is the polynomial $P(G,x)$ with variable $x$ that gives the number of ways of coloring the graph $G$ with $x$ or fewer colors.

and

> The chromatic polynomial is the polynomial $P(G,x)$ with variable $x$ that gives the number of ways of coloring the graph $G$ with exactly $x$ colors.

I see that the number of colorings is the same in both the definitions upto $x=k$, where $k$ is the chromatic number of $G$. But, if $x>k$, I quite dont see how coloring the graph with $\textit{exactly}$ $x$ colors is the same as coloring it with $x$ or fewer colors. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Where have you seen the second definition (in particular, with the word "exactly") used?

Comment: @79037662 I found that on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial)

Comment: I did a Ctrl_F of "exactly" and couldn't find it in the definition for chromatic polynomial. The closest I found was a section on using exactly $k$ colours, but that wasn't a definition of chromatic polynomial.

Comment: @79037662 thanks, so then the question is redundant.Could you post this comment in a lengthy way so I could accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first definition is the correct one, I've never seen the term "chromatic polynomial" with the second definition.

The second definition is false, and is an incomplete form for chromatic polynomials.